# Security Warning on scripts, but only on desktop

Tags: windows-7, security, permissions, security-warning

Somehow over the weekend, my Windows 7 Enterprise (64-bit) computer at work seems to have developed an odd problem. I went to load a management console file (.msc) that I've had on my desktop for months, but this time it gave me a warning that looked something like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ygqP5.png]

I re-saved my MMC session into a separate .msc file on my desktop and *that* gives me a warning. I right-click a batch file on my desktop that I wrote several weeks ago and click edit. Same warning. I open notepad and make a new batch file, save it to my desktop, same warning.

Why am I getting this warning on every "executable" file **that I create** on my desktop? But wait, there's more...

If I save (for example) a batch file elsewhere on my computer, I don't get a warning. No warning if I put it on the C drive, or my profile base folder, or even my network mapped Z drive. But putting it on my desktop or a desktop subfolder gives me the warning.

- I checked the permissions and can't see anything different with, say,
  another subfolder in my profile.
- I checked to see if any scripts I
  create on my desktop get automatically tagged with alternate data
  streams, but they don't.
- Anyone else who logs into my computer under
  their profile (domain) doesn't have this issue.
- My desktop is not redirected.
- Still gives a warning in Safe Mode.
- Other computers that I log onto don't exhibit this behavior--it's only *my* machine, and specifically only on *my desktop*.
- I've already ran a chkdsk /f.

Does anyone know how to get at the security settings for this and make it stop being so overzealous? Please keep in mind that:

- I don't want to disable the security altogether. Having, say, a warning for a file fresh off the internet is a Good Thing in my opinion. But it shouldn't be squawking at me for files I create myself.
- I don't want to make a blanket inclusion list for .bat, .ps1, etc files because that just seems folly.
- Basically I don't want a workaround; I want a fix. Yes, I could just save my scripts and such to a different folder or a different drive. But I shouldn't have to.

Worst case, I could delete my profile folder and let it be recreated and maybe that'd fix it. I'd rather not, and call me crazy but I really want to know what's going on here!

Thanks for any ideas, and I should mention that I won't be able to try any suggestion until I next go to work. So sorry about any delayed responses due to that.